# Unsupported operation - Apps are not allowed to listen to device lock notifications

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

Apple rejected my app with title

> Unsupported operation - Apps are not allowed to listen to device lock notifications

I am using Darwin Notifications in the app.

Is there any valid alternative of Darwin notifications for checking Lock State?

Answer (score 6):

You could try `applicationProtectedDataWillBecomeUnavailable(_:)` method of `UIApplicationDelegate`. From [docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate)

> When the user locks the device, the system calls the app delegate’s
> applicationProtectedDataWillBecomeUnavailable(*:) method. Data
> protection prevents unauthorized access to files while the device is
> locked. If your app references a protected file, you must remove that
> file reference and release any objects associated with the file when
> this method is called. When the user subsequently unlocks the device,
> you can reestablish your references to the data in the app delegate’s
> applicationProtectedDataDidBecomeAvailable(*:) method.

Good Luck!

Comment: But unfortunately these methods do not work if user has not enabled passcode or touchID.

Answer (score 1):

Remove darwin notifications observer for get device lock state and use simple default method [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState.Search if you are using or any third party using this "com.apple.springboard.lockstate" inside project then remove it.

Now clean the project and upload with new binary .